# Wifi is not Working in my Asus Laptop on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless, asus

After installing ubuntu 14.10, my wifi is not working
Here are some outputs of command :

Output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:eb:e8:17:3b:76  
          inet addr:192.168.137.211  Bcast:192.168.137.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9eeb:e8ff:fe17:3b76/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16186 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:19612686 (19.6 MB)  TX bytes:1176569 (1.1 MB)


lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:142697 (142.6 KB)  TX bytes:142697 (142.6 KB)
```

i cant find wlan0 here on output.

Output of: `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev cb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4c70]
```

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03eb:8a41 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 064e:9700 Suyin Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0b95:7e2b ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772B
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `rfkill list all`

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Please suggest how to resolve.

Comment: Was the computer connected to internet via ethernet during the installation process?

Comment: Yes it was connected.

Comment: Try `modprobe -v iwlwifi`. Tell me if that works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried above command and rebooted too but still its not working.

Comment: Without rebooting?

Comment: I mean before rebooting too and after rebooting also it was not working.

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi` and `sudo modprobe -v asus-wifi`

Comment: If your internet was connected and the laptop failed to effectively download functioning drivers for your internal wifi card I can only assume this is yet another annoying bug of 14.04.  I am not yet using 14.04, and I'm very hesitant to for reasons related to the problem you describe.  If you wish to have a stable operating system may I recommend Ubuntu 12.04LTS which is supported for 2.5 more years.  Please do not use 12.10 as it is not a Long Term Support version and is no longer supported.

Comment: @gyropyge 14.10 is fine. I've had few issues with it, so far.

Comment: After running above command i am getting below error :insmod /lib/modules/3.16.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module asus-wifi not found.

Comment: okay. does it work?

Comment: No its not working.

Comment: @vickysingh, to be fair to Ubuntu, I suppose it would be reasonable to try both of the following.  Please toggle the wifi switch on your asus (I have three asus netbooks and they all have some sort of manual overide switch).  If that doesn't make it work, please plug in an external usb wifi adapter to see if Ubuntu is simply unable to communicate with the internal one, or if it is refusing to communicate via wifi due to some sort of security setting.

Comment: while running **sudo lshw -class network** command  i am getting this output> *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: cb
       width: 64 bits
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 9c:eb:e8:17:3b:76
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download this to desktop https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.18.1/backports-3.18.1-1.tar.xz
Right click and select extract here
Then

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential

cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.18-1
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

After a reboot it should work if you have the firmware, you can do this to check `ls /lib/firmware/ | grep iwlwifi-7260`

I would expect one of the next kernel updates to fix this in 14.10 as on recently has the 14.04 kernel been patched to fix issues with the (rev cb) card

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are a life saver. Its working now.

Comment: Please choose my answer as accepted as it may help others with the same issue

Comment: @Jeremy31 : I am also facing the same issue, and followed all the steps in your anser. I am also able to check that firmware is installed, but still my wifi is not working, It is not showing up in ifconfig. is there something else, I can try?